# Can't call static methods between activities

Tags: android

I am trying to call a static method from another activity to find a integer for a score:

```
public class HighscoreActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscore);

        TextView txtGuess = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtScore);
        int temp = MastermindGameActivity.getScore();
        String score = Integer.toString(temp);
        txtGuess.setText(score);

    }
}
```

by calling this method:

```
public static int getScore()
{
    return score;
}
```

Why will this not work? I keep getting

> 01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sam.android.mastermind/sam.android.mastermind.HighscoreActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at sam.android.mastermind.HighscoreActivity.blah(HighscoreActivity.java:27)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at sam.android.mastermind.HighscoreActivity.onCreate(HighscoreActivity.java:13)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>   01-14 21:28:54.347: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1485):
>    ... 11 more

The activity is defined in manifest.

Comment: its a null pointer exception. post the whole log

Comment: I added as much of the logcat log as I can, is there another way to get the log?

Comment: Exception is at blah function 27 line of highscoreActivity. Can you post that function

Comment: I know this post is 4 years old but I'm very curious: what caused the exception? I tried the same thing and it worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this..

```
MastermindGameActivity masterActivity = new MastermindGameActivity();

masterActivity.getScore();
```

Also you can try passing it as a intent  as i would recommend.

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
 intent.putIntExtra("Score" score);
```

And pull it out in the receiving activity

```
 Intent sender=getIntent();
     int score = sender.getExtras().getInt("Score");
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Kinda had the ahh moment for passing intent now so this was very helpful! :)